# How to delay 'not found' error until data has loaded in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm hitting this route: `http://site.dev/person/1`

And my component looks something like this:

```js
// PeopleComponent.vue

<template>

<div>
   <template v-if="person == null">
       <b>Error, person does not exist.</b>
   </template>

   <template v-else>
       <pre> {{ person }} </pre>
   </template>
</div>

</template>

<script>
export default {


    mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch('getPeople');
    }

    computed: {

      // represents the person whose id potentially matches the value of `/:id` in route.
      person(){ 
          let id = parseInt(this.$route.params.id)
          let person = null

          if(id > 0)
              person = this.$store.state.people.find(p => p.id == id)

          return person;
      }

    }



}
</script>

// [styles]
```

### What I'm doing in this component:

> I get an ID in my URL. The ID represents a specific resource being shown on this page. I have a `person()` computed property to retrieve the object whose ID matches the parameter in the URL from my Vuex store.

### The desired outcome:

> At the top of the page, I would like to display an error message if the object cannot be found (if say, for example, someone types an ID that doesn't exist in the array of objects in the store). If the item is found, a simple dump of the object is fine. **This currently works, but the delay between fetching the data from the API and finding the right object in the store seems to be just long enough to briefly show the error message as if the object could not be found when the page first loads. When tested with a slower network speed, this error message is visible for several seconds. I want to eliminate it such that it does not appear at all if the object exists.**

### What I've tried:

- `v-cloak` - tried applying this to every parent div, even the `div#app` itself, to no avail. I must be doing something wrong.
- `v-if` - as seen above in the example

Some pointers would be appreciated, thank you!

---

### Update 31/03/2020

As per Phil's suggestion, I tried to incorporate a flag to indicate when the page is ready. I did it in two different ways.

**Method #1**
Made the `mounted()` 'async' and added an await on the action that retrieves `people` from my API. Setting flag to true after it:

```js
async mounted() { 

  await this.$store.dispatch('getPeople');
  this.loaded = true;

}
```

But I still see the error message, briefly.

**Method #2**

Use a `then` callback on the action, and set the flag to `true` inside the callback

```js
mounted() {

  let vm = this

  vm.$store.dispatch('getPeople').then(() => {

      vm.loaded = true;

  })

}
```

Both methods don't stop the message from appearing.

I suspect that this is what's happening:

Core rule

> Error should ONLY show if `loaded=true` and `person=null`

1. Page loads, `loaded` is `false` and `person` is `null`. Error won't show.
2. Page does a call to get people from API. Error still isn't showing.
3. After the call, `loaded` has been set to `true`
   [At this point, `loaded` is `true` and `person` hasn't been resolved by the computed property yet, THIS is where I believe I'm seeing the error.]
4. Computed property finds the relevant record from the store on the next tick.
5. `Person` is no longer `null`, so the error disappears.

## Edit 01/04/2020

Answering Phil's question: `What does your getPeople() action look like?`

```js
getPeople({ commit })  {   
        axios.get('/get/people')
        .then(response => {
            commit("getPeople", response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
},
```

Comment: What exactly does your `getPeople` action look like?

Comment: See original post.

Comment: And there it is. All you need to do is add a `return` in front of that `axios` call. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ah, I see. So when I don't return the promise on the action, does the `.then()` simply execute as soon as the action is called - without waiting for completion?

Comment: Bingo! Returning the promise in your action allows consumers to rely on it for timing

Comment: That's working now, and I've learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need one more piece of state, for example *loading*.

Change your `getPeople` action to be [composable](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions), ie **return** the Axios `Promise` so that it waits for the async task to complete...

```js
getPeople ({ commit })  {
  // make sure you return the promise
  return axios.get('/get/people').then(response => {
    commit("getPeople", response.data)
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
    // also make sure you don't accidentally convert this to a successful response
    return Promise.reject(error)
  })
},
```

then try something like this

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({ loading: true }),
  async created () {
    // "created" fires earlier than "mounted"
    await this.$store.dispatch('getPeople')
    this.loading = false
  },
  computed: {
    // etc
  }
}
```

Now you can use `loading` in your template

```html
<div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>
<div v-else>
  <!-- your "person" template stuff goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Every action returns a promise, use the then method for variable change.

Comment: @Craig not by default they don't. You need to explicitly return the promise. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions. You'll also note I've used an async function and can therefore use `await` instead of `then`

Comment: My mistake, you're correct. Totally forgot [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) is responsible returning the promises at my end.

Comment: @Craig at least you're remembering to return them. Half the async questions on StackOverflow can be solved by adding `return` in front of the async call

Comment: Interesting. Sorry I haven't responded yet, I'll try this later.

Comment: @Phil Ok so I tried this, same issue. If `loading` is set to `true` the moment the async action is complete... there still a small gap between it and between the computed property finding the object loaded into the store by the action and returning it back. I can see the "Not found" message in that split second.

Comment: @BarryD. sounds like your action is completing before the async task is actually complete. Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: So I tried this in two different ways. Updated the question.

Comment: Also added my understanding how this is going down, and at which point I'm seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

## Note

> Although this was my initial solution - Phil's answer seems to explain the problem best, and give a more suitable solution. So I'm still using my loader, but instead of a configured timer, I'm now simply waiting for the Promise.

In the end I realised I'm asking the site to wait for an indefinite amount of time until information is retrieved. In that time, something has to happen. I had to ask myself "well, what *do* you want displayed there before the resource is retrieved?" as this can't happen instantaneously... so I added spinner in.

The problem is the "indefinite" part, though. I don't know how long to display the spinner for. so I configured a global `timeout` variable.

So

1) If timeout hasn't been reached and resource is empty, display loader

2) If resource has loaded, show resource

3) If resource is empty and timeout has been reached, display error message

I'm pleased with this as a solution.

Comment: Why bother using a timeout when promises can tell you exactly when data is available. You never answered my question about your `getPeople` action. I bet the problem is in there

Comment: Look. We've got code saying `if resource is null show error` and `else show resource` ok? The promise will tell me when it has received data, sure, but how long will that take? 200ms? 500ms? 10 seconds? In those brief milliseconds, `resource` IS `null`, and that will consequently display the `"not found"` error message. This is the entire issue from the start. It doesn't matter when the promise finishes if it's taking long enough to come back that it makes the error message briefly visible. Does this make sense? Sorry, which question didn't I answer?

Comment: If there's any sort of delay it means your action is resolving before it's actually complete. Again, what does your `getPeople` action look like?

Comment: Just a standard Vuex action mate, I've updated the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem I used Use Vue-progressbar here is the link

http://hilongjw.github.io/vue-progressbar/index.html

I have implemented in my project if you need help just let me know.

Comment: That looks like a progress-bar library. I'm not sure how I'd utilise that to solve this problem. I appreciate the offer to help. :)